# How to convert a .yyp file to .s in ASM 6502

Tags: nes

I want to convert a .yyp file to .s file

This files are ASM 6502 for Nintendo Entertainment System. I made a game with Game Maker IDE and now want to convert it to Assembly. Can I have some help ?

I were expecting that we could find a converter on the web, but... no. I didn't find. I can't do it myself because I'm a big newbie.